# Ajax Not Working with h:inputSecret

Tags: java, ajax, validation, jsf, jsf-2

Trying to display a *Required Message* for a Password field, however it is not working with Ajax, once the password is entered it disappears.
Currently its solely done by the *required* property of the `h:inputSecret`, however the Ajax would be much better, before doing the HTTP submit.
Relevant Snippet:

```
<h:inputSecret id="newPassword"
               value="#{changePassword.password}"
               autocomplete="off"
               required="true"
               requiredMessage="#{i18n['javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED']}">
          <f:ajax event="blur"
                  render="@this Password_Message"/>
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message id="Password_Message" for="newPassword" errorClass="error"
           tooltip="true" />
```

An answer with an illustrative explanation of why is this happening is very appreciated, still learning JSF 2.0 :)

Comment: so, the validation is ok. but the only problem is that the field is reseted?

Comment: Validation is OK, because after typing a Password and trying to type the confirmation, the entered Password disappears..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added a `render="@this"` to the input element which causes that the whole input element will be rerendered when ajax request has finished. By default, [`<h:inputSecret>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html) values are not redisplayed after a form submit due to security reasons. The [tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html) also tells it literally:

> Render the current value of the component as the value of the "value" attribute, if and only if the "redisplay" component attribute is the string "true".

The same story applies on ajax rerendering of `<h:inputSecret>` fields. You can however force redisplaying by adding `redisplay="true"`.

```
<h:inputSecret redisplay="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this messageid" />
</h:inputSecret >
```

Or just get rid of `render="@this"`, because this is in essence completely unnecessary.

```
<h:inputWhatever>
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="messageid" />
</h:inputWhatever>
```

Comment: "By default, password field values are not redisplayed after a form submit due to security reasons." This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks as always!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I improved the answer a bit to add some documentation links.